# youtube and other video links not played in chromcast ios app

Tags: ios, youtube-api, video-streaming, chromecast

I am working on an ios app where I need to play youtube and other websites's video in app as well as need to cast it on chromcast. I have followed Google's official code example from here  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-ios/#0  I am able to play several video links which has extensions like .mp4 but not able to play youtube video url.

working url :-

http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4

but can't play youtube link like this
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfV-0Yv5vNY

I am passing video link and other data in bellow code when user tap on play button while the chromcast it connected.

```
GCKMediaInformation *mediaInformation =
  [[GCKMediaInformation alloc] initWithContentID:
          @"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgNSAXGVY8A"
                                      streamType:GCKMediaStreamTypeNone
                                     contentType:@""
                                        metadata:metadata
                                  streamDuration:0
                                      customData:nil];

  [_mediaControlChannel loadMedia:mediaInformation autoplay:YES     playPosition:0];
```

My chromcast receiver type is default and I am using this key "kGCKMediaDefaultReceiverApplicationID" for casting on default receiver.

I have searched so may question for this issue but almost all the questions are related to android application. 
so can anybody tell me whats is wrong with this? also I want to know that should I need to use custom receiver for youtube video player or I can use default one.
any help will be appreciate.

Comment: are you able to do this?, i'm facing same problem, need your help @Prince

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the YT urls, like the one you have mentioned, in a default receiver for casting purposes. If you insist on playing YT videos in your own receiver, you'd need to write a custom receiver and embed a YT player in your receiver and handle communication with your receiver yourself. There are also limitations to this solution; for example you cannot skip ads, etc.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your helpful reply. now I clearly understand that I need to write custom receiver for YT player videos. now can you please suggest me any official sources to create custom receiver? and one more question is that can I play other video url like dailymotion and player.pl videos with the help of custom receiver?

Comment: On our GitHub page, you can see a full receiver that is similar to the Styled/Default receiver. There are simpler receivers as well. Finally, read through the documentation on the developer site; it covers both sender and receiver components. As for DailyMotion and player.pl, I am not familar with their streams so can't comment.

Comment: Alright sir I will check it and try to integrate with my app. thank you for your support.